# Populating Jinja2 Template with Ansible Variables?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

In my Ansible playbook I am trying to set custom variables and then use those variables to populate a license file that I have in json. My idea is something like this.

```
   vars:
     customFields:
        unique_key: unique_value
        unique_key1: unique_value1
```

I would then populate the license.json using the template module and jinja2 in this way:

```
{
    "customer": "{{ customer_name }}",
    "validTil": "{{ lic_valid_till }}",
    {% for field in customFields %}
    "customFields": {
        "{{ field.key }}":"{{ field.value }}"
    }
    {% endfor %}
}
```

Am I doing this the right way and is something like this supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's supported. Use [items()](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#list-of-control-structures)

```
    {% for key, value in customFields.items() %}
    "customFields": {
        "{{ key }}":"{{ value }}"
    }
    {% endfor %}
```